# Не отображается файл "MainPage.xaml"

Tags: c#, uwp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь создать проект универсального приложения windows " Пустое приложение ( универсальное приложение для Windows ) ", но не отображается файл "MainPage.xaml". Что делать? ( Язык С# )

Comment: А какая у вас версия Windows?

Comment: У вас версия Windows 10 меньше, чем версия, создаваемого приложения, обновите ОС, либо понизьте версию приложения, это можно сделать в свойствах проекта

Comment: И, пожалуйста, текстовую информацию выкладывайте *текстом*, а не картинкой (и уж тем более не фото)

Comment: Выпуск  Windows 10 Домашняя, версия 1607, 64 разряд

Comment: @Nexsus24e, версия сборки: http://wpleaks.com/kak-proverit-kakaya-u-vas-sborka-windows-10-za-dva-prostyh-shaga.html

Comment: Могу поменять только минимальную версию windows. Не могу поменять целевую версию. Что делать?

Comment: Обновляйте ОС...

Comment: Только что проверял ОС на обновления, все обновления установлены.

Comment: 1709 последняя, обновляйтесь до нее

Comment: Обновил Windows , помогло , спасибо!